# Is github tracking source branch changes in pull request after pull request was merged?

Tags: github

I have created a GitHub pull request from master/main branch instead of creating from my dedicated branch by mistake.
This pull request is already merged and closed.

Would GitHub track any new changes I would make to my repository/branch in this pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would GitHub track any new changes I would made to mine repository/branch in this pull request?

Not in this (merged and closed) PR, but you can:

- fetch (in order to update `origin/main`)
- rebase your dedicated branch on top of origin/main (`git switch dedicated; git rebase origin/main`)
- push and create your PR from there.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way I wanted to be then. I was afraid that even if PR is closed it would be updated by my commits (normally github suggests deleting branch right after PR is closed but I would not like to delete master/main).